# Visual Indicators

Tags: website-design, html, css

[image]I am a newbie to UI. I have seen in google and other sites that whenever a person visits for the first time he will be presented with the visual indicators such as Ok, skip , got it etc.. I need to know whether there are any such examples I can find online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this pattern being used repeatedly - and I love it! I believe it follows from the 'blank slate' and 'how-to tutorial' patterns. Most of the Google products which have the new material design use this pattern. You can search for online how to's to find the examples you seek.

You can implement your own with tools like:
http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could take.

**1. Review what you've seen before**

To see the "early experiences" or "transfer-user" content again, why don't you create a new account, and then relive the experience? Or you may be able to switch off/opt out, and then opt back in, to see if you get to see it again.

**2. Look for examples in a pattern library**

There are several sites that collect design patterns, and you could check there for the kind of examples you seek:

- [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/UX-Design-Patterns.aspx)
- [UIPatterns](http://ui-patterns.com/)
- And also [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) and [this](http://patternry.com/) and [this](http://patternbrowser.org) and many others.

**3. Try building something, and then test it with real users**

Since you're new to UI, this will seem intimidating, so you might prefer to focus on the first two suggestions, for now.

It may seem overwhelming, at first. Keep at it.

I hope that helps you move forward a bit. :)